# PHP - How to add a transparent color layer on a image using GD?

Tags: php, image, colors, gd, transparent

Is there anyway to add a transparent color layer on a image using GD?

Here is an example. I am receiving a image looks like on the left-hand side (the image gots a transparent background). If I pass in a color like #ff0000 to the program, I want to add a 50% transparent color layer onto the image, but only to the area that got things on it, the result image will still got a transparent background, looks like on the right-hand side.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvuWm.png)

```
<?php
    $img = 'color.png';
    $hex = "#ff0000";
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
    list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x");
    $img_a = imagecreatefrompng($img);
    imagealphablending($img_a, true);
    $layer = imagecolorallocatealpha($img_a, $r, $g, $b, 50);
    imagefilledrectangle($img_a, 0, 0, $width, $height, $layer);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($img_a);
    imagedestroy($img_a);
?>
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at the [imagealphablending](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) function

Comment: I know how to add a 50% layer on to the image, but it will cover the whole image, and I want only the objects that on the image be covered but not the background. And may I ask what is function imagealphablending used for?